# Mostrar imagen en imageview AndroidStudio desde archivo local

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Necesito armar la ruta de una imagen guardada en un folder del dispositivo, para poder mostrarla en un imageview**

**Las imagenes se descargan y buscandolos aparecen**

**Si me pueden orientar de como armar la url o la forma para obtener el file, muchas gracias**

Tengo un proceso que descarga imagenes en el celular en el siguiente folder:

```
String ruta = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/modelos/" + productoSeleccionado;
...
 //le indico al donwload manager donde bajarlas
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(ruta, "003.gif");
```

Esto funciona y me descarga los archivos en /data/cache/modelos/pro_tem

Cuando intento mostrarlo con el siguiente code

```
//muestro la primer imagen (003)
String nombreArchivoImagen = "003.gif"; 

//TODO REVISAR SI LA RUTA ESTA BIEN, EVIDENTEMENTE NO ESTA BIEN PORQUE NO LO ENCUENTRA
String ruta =  Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/modelos/" + productoSeleccionado+"/"+nombreArchivoImagen;

File imgFile = new  File(ruta);
Log.i("ruta",imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

//TODO FALLA AL INTENTAR ABRIR EL ARCHIVO, CONTINUAMENTE DICE QUE NO EXISTE
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    previsualizacionProducto.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
else
{
    Log.i("ruta","no encontrado");
}
```

Continuamente, me muestra en el log "no encontrado".

Creo que le estoy pasando mal la ruta, cualquier recomendación es bienvenida!!!

EDIT

Probe reemplazar *getRootDirectory()* por *getDownloadCacheDirectory()*

```
String ruta =  Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()+"/modelos/" + productoSeleccionado+"/"+nombreArchivoImagen;
```

Pero me sigue sin cargar la imagen en el imageview. En el log, se imprime "no encontrado"

Comment: si tienes la posibilidad de usar picasso, aca hay una solucion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681349/2989467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usaste `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` debes usar [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) para obtener el archivo de acuerdo a la ruta del archivo guardado en el directorio publico externo.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), ruta );
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si sea solo un error del ejemplo, pero en tu código el nombre del archivo está hardcoded con el string `"nombre_archivo"`, y sin embargo al intentar obtener el archivo, el nombre del mismo pasado como parámetro es `"003.gif"`.

Comment: Lo de "nombre_archivo" lo puse como ejemplo

Comment: Edite la pregunta para no dar esa confusión

Comment: ¿Seguro que se puede guardar archivos en el rootDirectory?, según la documentación es read-only. Podrías probar guardando tu archivo en el getCacheDir().

Comment: ¿Has probado de colocar manualmente una imagen en otro directorio , y cambiar la ruta en el codigo de forma provisional?¿ has probado si esa imagen se sube correctamente?

Comment: Hola! Cambie el rootDirectory por getDownloadCacheDirectory(). Los archivos se descargan, si uno abre una ventana y buscas los archivos se descargan.

Comment: Mi error es como formular la ruta para poder mostrarlo, ahi es donde estoy fallando